# how to develop an ios app using php

Tags: php, ios, ios-app-extension

I have already fully developed website using `php` and `mysql`,now i want to develop an `ios` app for the website, my doubt is it possible to use the same `php` coding in `phonegap` or `xcode` to develop an app for `ios` ?

Answer (score 7):

First of all are you want to create app store application Or a mobile based website ? Its true that you can create a mobile based website with PHP. But app store application you have to write code by using Objective-c or swift. You can also create cloud-enabled native mobile app by php and using Zend Studio for overall clarification you can see this link http://venturebeat.com/2012/10/23/php-developers-you-must-see-this-creating-a-cloud-enabled-native-mobile-app-in-10-minutes-or-less-in-zend-studio/#DwUZXI6xuZID33CY.99

Answer (score 1):

You cannot develop an iOS application in PHP.  Your best option is to expose your web site functionality via JSON and then you can develop an iOS app to interact with your site that way.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer of your query is NO.
If you were related to .net you could be able to created iOS/Android/Windows app using xamarin.
For native iOS app you have to write code in objective C or swift. For phonegap and titanium you have to write code in CSS, Java Script and HTML.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible, because, `XCode` understands `Objective-C` (or `Swift`) and `PhoneGap` understand `Javascript` but no one can understand `php` at all.

However, you can either make your website responsive (at least) for iOS devices and then create a single view controller app (in `XCode`), which having a single view controller with a `UIWebView`, load your website into web view, and everything will be look/feel as in your website. This may be the best way to have a website and its app when you don't want to spent (too much) extra money or you don't know how to make an app for `iOS` (or any other platform).

For a note, the same you can do with `Windows`, `Android` and `Blackberry` to make an app for those platforms.

Let me know if you want to get more help on this (for `iOS` app only) and I'll comment my self here.